# Postfix restrict which users can send out without authentication

Tags: linux, email, centos, postfix, smtp

Possibly a simple question but I'm trying to lockdown which users can send email from the local machine. I've locked down which ones can receive by running newaliases on an /etc/postfix/allowed_recipients file and setting something similar to
`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_recipients, reject`
It works, but how can I do the same for sender restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unlisted_sender, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix-internal/localusers, reject
```

Inside localusers, list each OK address

```
joe@example.com  OK
fred@example.com  OK
```

or you can add a domain and then list only blocks

```
example.com   OK
goofy@example.com       550 Account compromised
stinky@example.com      550 Account closed
```

Comment: when I try to use newaliases on that file it complains, is there a better way to generate the .db?

Comment: Newaliases is only for alias files, generally /etc/aliases.  Postfix files are compiled with postmap command.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the postfix documentation. http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html